# How to Boot FAT Flash Drive with Ubuntu Installer

Tags: ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, fat32

I have a 1.86 GB Flash Drive and it is a FAT File System. I have downloaded the Ubuntu ISO. I need to be able to boot the flash drive with the Ubuntu ISO and be able to install it to another computer by booting from the flash drive. How do I do this?

Comment: Use the search or ask google instead. There are so many, so so many detailed information about creating USB boot disks for wide variety of operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already mounted the ISO to the USB drive? From there, you should be able to boot to Ubuntu on any computer having a properly configured BIOS.

You can try to use an application such as http://www.isotousb.com/ or use default ubuntu tools for creating a usb installer.

Cited from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick:

## Creating a bootable Ubuntu USB flash drive from Ubuntu

### Install and run usb-creator

You can find usb-creator-gtk in the Unity Dash by typing "Startup Disk Creator" (Ubuntu Desktop) or usb-creator-kde in K-Menu-->Applications-->System-->Startup Disk Creator (Kubuntu). If it is not there, then you can install it using the [Synaptic Package Manager](/community/SynapticHowto) or [Ubuntu Software Center](/community/UbuntuSoftwareCenter)

1. Insert and mount the USB drive.  Inserting the USB drive should auto-mount it.
2. Start usb-creator.  It looks like this in 13.10:

Image: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=usb-creator-gtk_erase-disk.png

1. in the top pane of usb-creator, pick the .iso file that you downloaded.
2. if the .iso file isn't listed, click "Other" to locate and select the .iso file that you downloaded.
3. Alternately, if you have a CD or DVD-ROM with the Ubuntu version you want to install on the USB flash drive, insert it in your CD-ROM drive and usb-creator can use that.
4. It is not necessary to erase the USB flash drive, however it is advisable that you do so.
5. Select the first bootable partition on the USB device as the disk to use
6. The bootable partition should be formatted as either a FAT16 or FAT32 filesystem. This is the default for most USB flash drives.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Format the Flash Drive to an NTSF File System

2.) Download the Linux Universal USB Installer http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

3.) Boot from the Flash Drive. (F10/F12 on your setup screen)

4.) Follow the instructions provided whether you want to Try or Install Ubuntu